# Is it a valid structure: requirement for something/someone to do/be something

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it a valid structure in English: requirement for something/someone to do/be something?

In particular, are the prepositions correctly chosen?

For example:

> 1. It is a requirement for lengths of table bases to be match.

> 2. This rule implies the requirement for car owners to have insurance.

> 3. I hate this rule that is the requirement for students to cut their hair short.

Comment: *It is a requirement **that** lengths of table bases [should] match*. I think because the subject in the second example, *(car owners),* is a "conscious entity", it's not so clunky if you use ***for*** there. But I'd still prefer *This rule implies the requirement that car owners [should] have insurance* there too. I may be mistaken, but I suspect if you always use relativiser ***that*** in such contexts your text will always be at least "acceptable" - but if you use ***for***, sometimes it won't work very well.

Comment: For example, I really don't like *It is a requirement **for** this form to be completed in ink* (as opposed to *It is a requirement **that** this form **be** completed in ink*). And tthere are probably other similar contexts where ***for*** sounds even worse. Avoid it everywhere, is my "quick and dirty" advice.

Comment: According to your suggestion about the first sentence, why have you omitted "be"? Is there any particular reason? Is _"It is a requirement that lengths of table bases [should] be match"_ wrong?

Comment: The only possible way to incorporate the "unmarked infinitive" ***be*** into your example is if we change the existing "main" verb to past tense ***matched*** and use it "adjectivally" in a "passive" construction: *It is a requirement that lengths of table bases [should] be **matched***. Note that in all my examples (which feature effectively "subjunctive" verb usages), the actual word ***should*** is effectively an optional stylistic choice (it's always *implicitly* present, even if not *explicitly* included in the text).

Comment: ...but note that ***rule*** and ***requirement*** are more or less synonymous anyway, so native speakers wouldn't normally include both in the same utterance. Just *I hate this rule that students must cut their hair short* gets the message across much better.

Comment: @alireza not the place to ask this, but you're not the famous chess player are you

Comment: @PeterKapteyn No!